# If $a_n=n^x(n^{1/n^2}−1)$, show that $\ln{(1+a_n/n^x)} = \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let 
>   $$a_n=n^x(n^{1/n^2}−1).$$ 
>   Show that 
>   $$\ln{(1+a_n/n^x)} = \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}. $$

It is on the study guide for my final exam, which is tomorrow so I am trying to figure it out. Thanks

I really can't figure this out

Comment: rearrange the expression for $a_n$ so that on the righthand side only $n^{1/n^2}$ remains and then take $\ln$ on both the sides, note that $\ln a^b = b \ln a$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n^x}\right)&=\ln\left(1+\frac{n^x(n^{1/n^2}-1)}{n^x}\right) && \text{(using the definition of $a_n$)}\\\\
&=\ln\left(1+(n^{1/n^2}-1)\right)&& \text{(canceling the $n^x$)}\\\\
&=\ln(n^{1/n^2}) && \text{(canceling the $+1$ and $-1$)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\ln(n) &&\text{(general property that $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$)}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Divide both sides by $n^x$, and add $1$ to both sides, then take $\ln $ both sides.